# how to get id of checked group radio from radio button in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

Is there any way to get value of grouped radio buttons?
this code dont work for me:

```
self.pb1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.rbtn_1_state(self.rb1_1.ischecked(),self.rb1_2.ischecked()))

def rbtn_1_state(self, rb1_1_chk,rb1_2_chk):
    print("radio button 1 function is called")
    if rb1_1_chk:
        rb1_state=[1,0]
    if rb1_2_chk:
        rb1_state = [0, 1]
    else:
        rb1_state = [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox() 

        self.rb1_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("rb1_1", self.groupBox)
        self.rb1_1.setChecked(True)
        self.rb1_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("rb1_2", self.groupBox)

        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb1_1)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rb1_2)

        self.lb1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.pb1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pb1")
        self.pb1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.rbtn_1_state(
                                      self.rb1_1.isChecked(),
                                      self.rb1_2.isChecked()))

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.lb1)
        self.vLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.pb1)

    def rbtn_1_state(self, rb1_1_chk, rb1_2_chk):
        self.lb1.setText("rb1_1-> {} , rb1_2-> {}".format(rb1_1_chk, rb1_2_chk))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = Window()
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That's great but I have another question? in multi-thread application we use two thread one for gui another for backend calculation what is the best way if I want to send radio button to another class when a push button is pressed in another way my backend program get some setting from group of radio buttons I call rbtn_1_state but get this error: AttributeError: 'QRadioButton' object has no attribute 'is checked'

Comment: You can be helped incorrectly if publish a new question, insert an example which can be checked and clearly describe your problem.